# Getting Power Bi Embedded URL

Tags: powerbi

I want to get the embedded URL of my existing reports. Is there any option to get those URL in a list view?

Answer (score 0):

As per i know, currently there is no api for retrieving all reports.
For more information, you can refer [Power BI Api reference](http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all reports which have embed code. However you need an extra click to get the embedded code.

[image]